# MVC: Displaying table data not working as expected

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-4, html-table, viewbag

I have this table in database:

[image]

I'm trying to display the the values (`ModuleID` and `DateEntered`) in the browser as table.
I'm using viewbag to pass the value to my view, which is not quite the right way as I get just one row right now. What I'm doing right now is

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var modules = (from entries in _db.Modules
                           orderby entries.DateEntered
                           select entries);
            ViewBag.entries = modules.ToList();
            return View();
        }
```

How can I get all rows from the table in above picture and pass it to view?
In my view I currently have:

```
@using BootstrapSupport

    @model Sorama.DataModel.SIS.ModuleStock.Module

    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "Index";
        Layout = "~/Views/shared/_BootstrapLayout.basic.cshtml";
    }

    <table class="table table-striped">
        <caption></caption>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                   Module ID
                </th>

                <th>
                    Date Entered
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tr>
             @foreach (var entry in ViewBag.entries)
            {
                <td>@entry.ModuleId</td>
                 <td>@entry.DateEntered</td>
            }
             <td>
                    <div class="btn-group">
                        <a class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                            Action
                            <span class="caret"></span>
                        </a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details")</li>
                                @if (Request.IsAuthenticated && HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("Admin"))
                                {
                                    <li class="divider"></li>
                                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit")</li>
                                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete")</li>
                                }



                        </ul>
                    </div>

                </td>
        </tr>

    </table>
```

This shows the values of entire row and not just (`ModuleID` and `DateEntered`)
This is what I get in browser[image: Browser output].

To sum up, I want to get all the rows from table but only specific columns.
Which is not happening at current situation. 
Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
 public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ABCList abc=new ABCList();
        var modules = (from entries in _db.Modules
                       orderby entries.DateEntered
                       select new ABC {
                           id=entries.id,
                           ModuleTypeId=entries.ModuleTypeId,
                           ModuleId=entries.ModuleId,
                           DataEntered=entries.DataEntered
                        });
        abc.settings = modules.ToList();
        return View();
    }

  public class ABC
  {

    public long Id{ get; set; }
    public long ModuleTypeId{ get; set; }
    public string ModuleId{get;set;}
    public DateTime DataEntered{ get; set; }
  }

  public class ABCList{
    public List<ABC> Settings { get; set; }
  }
```

View

```
  @model ABCList
  @foreach (var entry in Model.Settings)
 {
 <tr>
    <td>@entry.ModuleId</td>
    <td>@entry.DateEntered</td>
    <td>
        <div class="btn-group">
            <a class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                Action<span class="caret"></span>
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details")</li>
                @if (Request.IsAuthenticated && HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("Admin"))
                {
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete")</li>
                }       

            </ul>
        </div>    
    </td>
 </tr>
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You misreading your results. There are 3 records with 2 fields each displayed in one row. You have single `<tr>` in your view and you insert values from `ViewBag` in `<td>` tags. You should put new `<tr>` for each of your record in `ViewBag`.

It should look more like this:

```
@foreach (var entry in ViewBag.entries)
{
    <tr>
        <td>@entry.ModuleId</td>
        <td>@entry.DateEntered</td>
        <td>
            <div class="btn-group">
                <a class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                    Action<span class="caret"></span>
                </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details")</li>
                    @if (Request.IsAuthenticated && HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("Admin"))
                    {
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit")</li>
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete")</li>
                    }       

                </ul>
            </div>    
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

Comment: Thanks!!! that worked. But is ViewBag a good way to pass the data to view?? What if I want to show name of `ModuleTypeId` which comes from another table?

Comment: Using strongly-typed ViewModels is highly recommended over using ViewBag. You should pass your model as parameter to the view (`return View(model);`) and use `@model IEnumerable<Module>` in you view (you can remove `@model` from your view now, when you do not use it anyway). Then, you can access your model in the view from `Model` property : `@foreach (var entry in Model.Entries)`

Comment: No View Bag is not good approach create Model and bind values in Models. Use model to display values.

Comment: @Amit Can you give an example as an answer. How I can pass values from my controller in such case without using Viewbag and how can I use them in View